# How to check if 3 days have passed

Tags: swift, date

How can I check to download some data every 3 days? All I need to do is check if 3 days or more have passed when the user opens the app, and if so, for the app to download some things? Here's what I have so far for comparing dates:

```
var shouldDownload: Bool = false

extension NSDate: Equatable {}
extension NSDate: Comparable {}

public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 == rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}    

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 < rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}

extension Int {
    var days: NSTimeInterval {
        let DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24
        var days:Double = Double(DAY_IN_SECONDS) * Double(self)
        return days
}
let lastChecked = NSDate()

let interval = NSDate(timeInterval: 3.days, sinceDate: lastChecked)
let today = NSDate()

if interval > today {
    shouldDownload = true
}
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  The question isn't so bad.  OP, are you asking how to store the data or how to use the date/time functions?

Comment: His question lacks of research. He hasn't shown what he has tried so far.

Comment: OP did show no effort to find a solution. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @thumbtackthief I am asking how to use the date/time functions

Comment: due to DST you cannot expect a day being `60 * 60 * 24` seconds long.

Comment: Doing date calculations ends up being VERY tricky. There are TONS of edge cases. Much better to use NSCalendar and let it do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it with NSCalendar in the end, thanks for the help

Comment: To those that downvoted this question (@vikingosegundo?), the OP went back and added code, as well as clarifying comments. Can you please reconsider your down-votes, and think seriously about removing them? I think the down votes are undeserved in this case.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer so you can delete the question. Er, no, I guess I'm not. It seems I can't delete an answer once it's accepted.

Comment: @DuncanC no it's fine, leave it. Somebody else might have the same problem. I'll get back the reputation soon enough

Comment: Sorry about that. I upvoted your question and it's back to a zero total now. (4 up, 4 down.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Every time your app launches or comes back to the foreground, do the following:

- Read a saved NSDate from NSUserDefaults.
- Figure out the number of midnights that have passed from the saved
  date until now. (Do a search in the Xcode docs on "Midnights" to find
  NSCalendar code for calculating the number of days between 2 dates.)
- Save today's date to NSUserDefaults as the new saved date

I wrote this method as an extension to NSDate:

```
  /**
  This function calcuates an ordinal day number for the receiver 
  using the Gregorian calendar.

  :returns: an integer day number
  */

  func dayNumber() -> Int
  {
    let calendar = DateUtils.gregorianCalendar
    return calendar.ordinalityOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,
      inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitEra, forDate: self)
  }
```

It uses a class DateUtils to manage a single instance of the Gregorian NSCalendar. That lets me avoid creating a new instance of the Gregorian calendar for each date operation I need to do.

```
class DateUtils
{
  static let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out though like you said with the NSCalendar. It was pretty simple in the end!

Comment: Hey Duncan, I'm having problems with my account, it's putting a ban on me. I want to delete this question to get back my ability to ask questions, is there any way you could help me out and delete your answer so I can delete the question?

Comment: I up-voted your question. I think your question was reasonable, and especially with the edits showing what you tried, it shows decent effort. Is that enough for you to get your posting privileges back? I'd rather not delete my answer If I don't have to, since it could help somebody else.

Comment: thanks for up-voting but I still can't ask any questions...I guess I'll just have to answer some more questions and get back reputation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this simple function:

```
func isPassedMoreThan(days: Int, fromDate date : Date, toDate date2 : Date) -> Bool {
    let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day]
    let deltaD = Calendar.current.dateComponents( unitFlags, from: date, to: date2).day
    return (deltaD ?? 0 > days)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version:

```
func isPassedMoreThan(days: Int, fromDate date : Date, toDate date2 : Date) -> Bool {
    let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day]
    let deltaD = Calendar.current.dateComponents( unitFlags, from: date, to: date2)
    return deltaD > days
}
```

Comment: Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateComponents' and 'Int'

Comment: put `.day` by the end of deltaD to get days int